# Regex matching unwanted special Chars

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

Could someone explain to me why the following regex

```
^(?=.*\w)(?=.*[!@#$*_])(?!.*\s).{8,20}$
```

match : `test*~|-*test`

I'm trying to validate the following rules:

- Between 8 and 20 chars
- At least one special char from `!@#$*_`
- Other than that, only alpha-numeric

Comment: Nice service for explaining regexes: [link](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E(%3F%3D.*%5Cw)(%3F%3D.*%5B!%40%23%24*_%5D)(%3F!.*%5Cs).%7B8%2C20%7D%24)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern requires

(1) (?=.*\w)   at least one word char

(2) (?=.*[!@#$*_]) at least one of those special chars

(3) (?!.*\s)  no space char

(4) .{8,20}   any char, from 8 to 20 long

Your input test*~|-*test  matches the pattern

For what you're after I'd use

```
^(?=.*[!@#$*_])(?=.*\w)[\w!@#$*_]{8,20}$
```

(1) (?=.*[!@#$*_]) at least one special char

(2) (?=.*\w)  at least one word char

(3) [\w!@#$*_]{8,20}  word char or special char, 8 to 20 times